# Can rMBR 2015 (or other) can run external display/TV without fan noise?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have a 2015 rMBP and when I am connecting external display (in my case it is 720p TV with HDMI cable) the fans starting to blow and never go below certain (hearable) line. I have seen some quiestions here regarding this noise and in google as well but all I see is people suggesting to reduce heat (with some external devices) or reduce load (which I don't have or even if have CPU is MAXed at 40-50 percent sometime jumping to 100 but not that much when compiling and etc). I am considering buying a 4k monitor and concerned that macbook will work with it that way all the time (which i don't want). If you are using MBP with external monitor (be it HD, 4k, HDMI or DP) can you confirm that fans is blowing all the time or this is something with my mac? I was trying to monitor the system, reset smc, no dust inside and etc and seems everything is okay, mac is working perfectly when not connected to monitor, there is no big load and etc. When connecting to TV and even doing nothing it will start to blow in some time.

Comment: Do the fans immediately go up just by connecting the TV, without the MacBook doing anything at all (no video playing, ...)?

Comment: yes, i connect the hdmi cable, picture blinks (assume it is switching gpu) and the fans is slowly go app without me doing anything. If something is working video, safari and i am doing something it happens faster.

Comment: Have you tried with a different monitor/TV? Is activity monitor showing any CPU behaviour despite you not using the device?

Comment: No I only have this TV at the moment and want to order 4K monitor and that is why I want to know if this is a normal behaviour for a macbook connected to external monitor.

Comment: Regarding loading here what I have now, I have only this window of safari opened (no other apps opened, hazel, sherlock and dropbox in the background).

Comment: CPU - 48-50C, FANS - 2154RPM, 2000RPM. CPU load - 2-5%. Now when I am connecting cable with TV and waitng 10 minutes: Fans go up to 3100, 2900, CPU temp is about 60, but this all without doing anything and not touching anything, if I am actually start watching some videos, do xcode and etc it quickly go up to 5000-6000RPM.  But this behaviour is only if connected to the external monitor, with only internal monitor RPMS are much lower going up only when doing something hard like video exporting or compiling.